# Express set header content response type

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, express

I am trying to set header content type to be application/json for universal links from IOS, but still response is with

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

but should be

```
'Content-Type', 'application/json'
```

My simple server.js looks like follows:

```
// Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

app.get(
  '/dist/.well-known/apple-app-site-association',
  function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('it is not console.logged');

    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.sendFile(
      path.join(__dirname + '/dist/.well-known/apple-app-site-association')
    );
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }
);
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  console.log('can log here');

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

How to set header conent type to be application/json?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `express.static`, which is the first middleware in your code, requests that match the files in the static folder will be handled by `express.static`. The files in `.well-known` probably do not have a `.json` extension, hence the content type will be inferred as `application/octet-stream` as this is the [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

What you could do is simply add the following middleware **before** the static middleware to ensure that all `.well-known` files will be served with `application/json` content type:

```
app.use('/.well-known',(req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
```

Comment: thx, but doesn't work :(. I tried also with different path but also doesn't work ```app.use('/dist/.well-known/*', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('hello world');
  
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
``` but I cannot even console.log inside of the first app.use()

Comment: Remove the `dist` from the path ..if it still does not work, show your request please, e.g. through `curl`.

Comment: nope still same, not sure how to show it. 
curl http://localhost:8080/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appID": "GF32XXXXX.lt.myApp",
             "paths": ["*"]
           }
       ]
   }
}

Comment: Weird, definitely works on my machine. Here's a link to a codesandbox where it works as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rain-0znge. Request it with `https://0znge.sse.codesandbox.io/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

Comment: no idea, but still have Content-Type: application/octet-stream. I tried also to deploy it with docker and nginx. ANd it works locally but cannot run it on heroku app. here is the question maybe you have some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204473/angular-with-docker-deploy-on-heroku

Comment: Well, if it works now locally, it's not an issue related to nodejs and we can close this question, right? I'll have a look at the other one..

Comment: no, it doesn't work with express server. I just meant that I also was trying with nginx and docker but neither with expres nor with nginx works :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228996/discussion-between-camel-and-eol).